# XML saved in sybase is well structured, Need it as single row

Tags: xml, database, sybase

I have a column in database of type txt, data is stored in well structured xml in this column.

I want this data in a single row,not as well structered. Whats the way to do that???

Comment: its single column of type text

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If the data is already in a column, then by definition, it is already in a single row as well. But maybe that's not what you mean? Please make an effort to clarify.

Comment: I solved this problem using replace function and replaced char(10) with ""

Comment: Next thing is there are white spaces between 2 xml tags is there any way to remove while querying?

Comment: example: <name>abcd</name>           <age>30</age> So this white space between name and age has to be removed

Comment: use this: STR_REPLACE(<your-string>, ' ', NULL)